# How can I say "that's her thing", in the sense of something that someone does well?

Tags: vocabulary, translation

> A: "Amy's drawing is definitely the best of the competition entries!"
>
> B: "Well, art **is her thing**"

To be 'someone's thing' can have a few different meanings, but here it means: it's the thing that someone does the best (of their skills) or is the most enthusiastic about. What's a good way to translate this phrase in Korean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

미술이 걔 특기잖아.  미술은 에이미 특기다. 특기 means special skill(s)   If you want to sound like more slang Korean, you can say 미술~하면 에이미지, meaning that when it comes to art, Amy stands out or you cannot discuss art without mentioning Amy